# Regex to get object parameters from string and get the value of those parameter from a JSON/Js Object

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have two strings and a Js object

```
var strArr = '$PARAMS["version"]["config"]$';
var strObj = "$PARAMS.version.config$;
```

and JS Object

```
var obj = {
    "version": {
        "config": {
            "prod": "stackoverflow"
        }
    }
}
```

String can come as strArr or strObj, I am trying to get a regex to extract version and config(and so on) from both strings and get the value for the same from Js obj

eg: `obj["version"]["config]`

I am able to solve this for strArr i.e '$PARAMS["version"]["config"]$', need to modify the regex in the getVal function below to get is working for strObj.

Also In the function below path can be either of strArr or strObj

```
function getVal(obj, path) => {
    let regex = /\["(.*?)"\]/mg;
    let m;

    while ((m = regex.exec(path)) !== null) {
        // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
        if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
            regex.lastIndex++;
        }

        if(typeof obj[m[1]] !== 'undefined') obj = obj[m[1]];
        else return obj[m[1]];
    }
    return obj;
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? ;P

Answer (score 0):

Changing the regex to **/.([\w]*)|["(.*?)"]/mg** 
and adding folowing line in the function fixed the problem
**else if(typeof obj[m[2]] !== 'undefined') obj = obj[m[2]];**

Final function looks like

```
function getVal(obj, path) {
                    let regex = /\.([\w]*)|\["(.*?)"\]/mg;
                    // let regex = /\["(.*?)"\]/mg;
                    let m;
                    while ((m = regex.exec(path)) !== null) {
                        // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
                        if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
                            regex.lastIndex++;
                        }
                        if(typeof obj[m[1]] !== 'undefined') obj = obj[m[1]];
                        else if(typeof obj[m[2]] !== 'undefined') obj = obj[m[2]];
                        //TODO: Add logic to through error if the parameter is not found
                    }
                    return obj;
                }
```